# How to Toggle off the Visibility of Tags NOT of a Specified Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, toggleclass

Here is the problem I'm trying to solve with Javascript.

I have a list of 4 items: `#item01` - `#item04`. Each has two kinds of characters: color and location, so I give each a color class and a location class and there are 2 colors (`.color01` - `.color02`) and 3 locations (`.location01` - `.location03`).
Each item has a menu with two buttons "same color" and "same location". 
When you click on "same color" of an item, only those items with the same color will remain and other items disappear. So for example, if you choose the "same color" button of `item01`, which has class `.color01` and class `.location01`, only item01 and item02 will remain on the page, because they share the same color/class `.color01`, and `item03` and `item04` will disappear, because they do NOT have the same color/class `.color01`. Similarly, when you click on "same location" in the menu of `item01`, only those items with the same location class remain, and others disappear.

I'm new to Javascript. I only know how to toggle on/off the visibility of items of certain ID, but I have no clue how to toggle on/off the visibility of items NOT of a specified CLASS. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="item" id="item01" class="color01" class="location01">
    <img src="01.img>
    <div class="menu" id="menu01"><a href="#" onclick="...">Same Color</a> | <a href="#" onclick="..."> Same Location </a></div>
</div>

<div class="item" id="item02" class="color01" class="location02">
    <img src="02.img>
    <div class="menu" id="menu02"><a href="#" onclick="...">Same Color</a>  | <a href="#" onclick="..."> Same Location </a></div>
</div>

<div class="item" id="item03" class="color02" class="location02">
    <img src="03.img>
    <div class="menu" id="menu03"><a href="#" onclick="...">Same Color</a>  | <a href="#" onclick="..."> Same Location </a></div>
<div>

<div class="item" id="item04" class="color02" class="location03">
    <img src="04.img>
    <div class="menu" id="menu04"><a href="#" onclick="...">Same Color</a>  | <a href="#" onclick="..."> Same Location </a></div>
<div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.location01, .location02, .location03 .color01, .color02 {display: block;}
```

Comment: add http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: question is not clear! please refresh the question.

Comment: I just re-edited my question. Hope it's clearer now. I'm sorry I can't really do [jsfiddle.net] because the code I wrote is just an example, but not the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $(document).not('.except_classname')
```

This will return all elements except the elements with class in .not() in the document.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate on your answer? Thanks!